# $xy$ and $x+y$ algebraic implies $x,y$ algebraic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K\supseteq F$ be a field extension and $x,y\in F$. Can someone
please explain to why the equivalence
$$
x,y\text{ algebraic over }F\ \Leftrightarrow\ x+y\text{ and }xy\text{ are algebraic over }F
$$ should hold ?

(the $\Rightarrow$ direction is fairly easy, and I did it, but I'm stuck at the other direction.)

Comment: Actually, it is $\implies$ direction that requires some work, certainly more than the other direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x$ and $y$ both satisfy the equation $X^2-(x+y)X+xy$, so they are algebraic over $F(xy, x+y)$. Now recall that if $F\subset K \subset L $ and $L/K$ and $K/F$ are algebraic, so is $L/K$. (You can prove this by using an argument about dimension, since every algebraic element is contained in a finite extension.)

Answer (score 8):

Look at the roots of $$\alpha^2 - (x+y) \alpha + xy$$