# $ab$ and $a+b$ algebraic implies $a,b$ algebraic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

$L/F$ be a field extension. Is it possible that $F (a,b)/F (ab,a+b)$ to be algebraic extension?  I've tried to find a field $K$ 
$F (a,b)/K$ is algebraic extension and $K$ is subfield of $F(ab,a+b)$. Fortunately if $a, b$ are algebraic over $F$, $F$ could be such $K$. But I cannot find such $K$ for any $a,b$. Is this kind approach wrong?

Comment: Thanks. Then that kind of method can be applied to show F(x)/F (x^2/x-1) algebraic? I proved it by setting a isomorphism between them.

Comment: **Exact dupe** of [$xy$ and $x+y$ algebraic implies $x,y$ algebraic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225441/xy-and-xy-algebraic-implies-x-y-algebraic) (and many others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a,b$ are roots of the quadratic polynomial $X^2-(a+b)X+ab$.
Hence $F(a,b)/F(ab,a+b)$ is algebraic of degree $1$ or $2$.

Comment: Thanks. Then that kind of method can be applied to show F(x)/F (x^2/x-1) algebraic? I proved it by setting a isomorphism between them.

Comment: Yes, if $\alpha=\frac{x^2}{x-1}$ then $x$ is a root of $X^2-\alpha X+\alpha$, hence $[F(x):F(\alpha)]=2$ or $=1$.